# Response Header validation in java

Tags: java, security, http, response, split

I am passing directly a user defined parameter in my response header. Which I have learned is not a good idea since that way user can manipulate header and it can lead to Cross site scripting attacks and other kind of multiple attacks.

https://www.fortify.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/python/header_manipulation.html

What I am doing for preventing this is validate the user input for "http response splitting" by replacing "\r" and "\n" characters with empty string "". Is this enough or I have to check for other characters also. Any pointers would be of great help.

This is my code.

```
if(response != null)
  {
   newResponse = response.replaceAll("[\r\n]", "");
  }
```

Is this enough for preventing this kind of attack or I should also validate for other characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A whitelist is much safer than a blacklist. Whether you can use a whitelist depends on how much you know about the user defined parameter.

More here:

http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/113.html

Comment: +1 to whitelist. specify the characters that *are* allowed. Don't assume you have a complete enough knowledge of all possible attack vectors and exploitation scenarios, such that you can enumerate and disallow all possible malicious strings/characters. There's always going to be one you didn't think of, especially in the world of unicode --or even malformed unicode codepoints.

Comment: Yes white listing is good approach. I am passing a file name in the response. 
I have changed my regular expression to.
if(response != null)
  {
   newResponse = response.replaceAll("[^\\\\ _a-zA-Z0-9-./]", "");
  }

@artbristol thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The information you give is insufficient for a proper answer. We would need to know what you do with the parameter value in order to tell whether your actions are good enough or not and what kind of an environment your code runs in. A short, 100% correct (but pretty useless) answer would be "no."

Security is not implemented by following simple bullets taken outside of their original context. You took it from Python context and placed it directly to Java context. You must understand your environment and what your code does completely. There is no silver bullet.

Comment: Misunderstood a part of the question and thus removed an irrelevant comment.